# Interpreting Generating Function Definition

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Consider the below definition of a generating function of a numerical sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$.

If there exists $s_0>0$ such that

$$A(s)\equiv\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_js^j$$

converges in $|s|<s_0$, then we call $A(s)$ the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)$.

My question:

1. What does it mean that it converges $|s|<s_0$? Can you put this in the $\varepsilon-\delta$ language? I assume this has to do with the radiance of convergence?
2. What is the intuition behind this generating function of a numerical sequence? Why do we care? I can relate to the moment generating function in probability. But the way MGFs are introduced in probability is in relation with the computation of CDF without further intuition. Literally, it is generating moments? One example I hear is that generating function techniques convert the problem of solving a recursion into the problem of solving differential equation. Can someone give a simple and pedagogical example?
3. In probability, we have a generating function of a random variable $X$ as

$$P(s)=Es^X.$$

What is $s$ here? Why does the generating function aid the computation of moments?

Comment: Phew .. a lot of questions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- May $P$ be the set of functions that can be written as a power series.
  $$ \forall A\in P, \exists s_0 \in \mathbb{R}, \forall N\in \mathbb{N}:$$
- $s\in\mathbb{R}, |s|<s_0, lim_{N->\infty} \sum_{k=0->N} a_j s^j = A(s) $
- $s = s_0, lim_{N->\infty} \sum_{k=0->N} a_j s^j$ might not converge
- $s > s_0, lim_{N->\infty} \sum_{k=0->N} a_j s^j$ does not converge

$s_0$ is called the radius of convergence (rayon de convergence) of $A$. If you want a $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof, you just have to do a regular one with the limit operator in front.

2. Generating functions are really common in statistics, probability, sequences and more generally **umbral** calculus. It is really convenient like in the example of MGFs. They are used, as you mentionned for differential equation. You try to find a family of solutions $A(s)\equiv\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_js^j$ and then find a recursion relation $a_j = f(a_{j-1}, a_{j-2},....)$ (because $A'(s) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty ja_js^{j-1} = = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (j+1)a_{j+1}s^{j}
   $) and then you can find $a_j$ and by knowing "standard" power series, you can often in exercises find a solution. It is also used in combinatorics to prove some properties. It has a lot of applications.

3.
The moment-generating function $M$ of a random variable $X$ is defined by:

$$ M_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf t) := \operatorname E \left(e^{\mathbf t^\mathrm T\mathbf X}\right)$$
In the 1-dimensional case, it becomes:

$$ M_{ X}( t) := \operatorname E \left(e^{ t X}\right)$$

$t$ is a variable because $M$ is a function. It is a variable with no real meaning, but that is convenient to get expressions with derivatives to the respect of $t$.